# Passing a QImage to a method - pointer confusion

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, object, qimage

I'm working on a QT image application.  For now I want to load an image from a file, display it, and then be able to change it to greyscale on a button click.

Here are my public declarations of the conversion function and image object

```
public:
QImage * MainWindow::greyScale(QImage * origin);
QImage myImage;
```

In my "Open File" action I initialise the image and display it in a label like this

```
myImage.load(fileName);

myImage = myImage.scaled(400, 300);
ui->imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(myImage));
```

Here is my Greyscale Conversion method

```
QImage * MainWindow::greyScale(QImage * origin){
QImage * newImage = new QImage(origin->width(), origin->height(), QImage::Format_ARGB32);

QColor oldColor;

for(int x = 0; x<newImage->width(); x++){
    for(int y = 0; y<newImage->height(); y++){
        oldColor = QColor(origin->pixel(x,y));
        int average = (oldColor.red()+oldColor.green()+oldColor.blue())/3;
        newImage->setPixel(x,y,qRgb(average,average,average));
    }
}

return newImage;
}
```

Now the problem I have is I'm not sure how to correctly call the conversion method and store the returned object in a new image.  I want to send my original image (myImage) in, but if I do it like this

```
QImage newPic = greyScale(myImage);
```

I get the error "cannot convert parameter 1 from 'QImage' to 'QImage *'

Do I need to pass a pointer or a reference or something?  I've tried multiple combinations but nothing is working.  I'm not entirely clear on the syntax

```
QImage * origin
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's change that call and understand it step by step, and for that you need to pay attention to 2 things: what the method **returns**, and what **arguments** it needs.

The method clearly allocates space for a new `QImage` and **returns** a pointer to that object. So the first change would address that:

```
QImage* newPic = greyScale(myImage);
```

Second, the method **expects** the memory address (pointer) of an existing `QImage` object. So we go ahead and give the address of `myImage`:

```
QImage* newPic = greyScale(&myImage);
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Your method receives a pointer to QImage as parameter. Either change it  to `QImage * MainWindow::greyScale(const QImage &origin)`, **or** declare `myImage` as a pointer: `QImage *myImage = new QImage (/*some params if needed*/);`